# Finding out the minimum extent size

Tags: oracle

For a given table space in Oracle, how does one find out the minimum extent size and if it is being logged.

I have had a look at the v$ tables without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer - if you are interested the view [`DBA_TABLESPACES`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/DBA_TABLESPACES.html#GUID-B28A7D79-24E3-49B5-B948-7C2277CB1FB8) has the values:

```
┌─────────────┬─────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│  MIN_EXTLEN │   NUMBER    │ Minimum extent size for this tablespace (in bytes)   │
├─────────────┼─────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│  LOGGING    │ VARCHAR2(9) │ Default logging attribute:LOGGING/NOLOGGING          │
└─────────────┴─────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Example:

```
select TABLESPACE_NAME, MIN_EXTLEN, LOGGING
from dba_tablespaces
```